# Reusable views in Play! Framework 2.6.2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm having a problem importing a partial/reusable view to a .scala.html file in the Play! Framework (2.6.2).

My reusable component is called _enhance.scala.html, in a folder called partials and has this modal code in it:

```
@()
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("css/modal.css")">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In another view I am trying to import it like so:

```
@import views.html.partials._enhance
```

And then use it like so:

```
@_enhance
```

In my understanding doing that should result in the modal being imported into the html of the page I'm importing it to. I am not getting any errors, but the result is this showing up on my screen:

> BaseScalaTemplate(play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat$@65195b0f)

This suggests the screen is rendering a string of the Object, from my understanding. Is there a bit I'm missing here?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@views.html.partials._enhance()` directly (replace @_enhance with it) and you do not need import in this case

Answer (score 0):

> And then use it like so:

```
@_enhance
```

You just forget the `()`:

```
@_enhance()
```

Will work for you